# Python: Cannot read from a FileStorage object

Tags: python, csv, flask, io

I have a `.xlsx` file and transformed it into a `.csv` file. Then I'm uploading the `.csv` file to a Python script I wrote, but an error is thrown.

Since the file is upload through HTTP, I'm accessing it with `file = request.files['file']`. This is returning a file of type `FileStorage`. After I'm trying to read it with the `StringIO` object as follows:

```
io.StringIO(file.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes
```

I also tried to read the file of `FileStorage` object this way:

```
file_data = file.read().decode("utf-8")
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 97: invalid start byte
```

Maybe it is interesting to note, that I'm being able to read the file directly, i.e. as a csv file, with the following code:

```
with open('file_path', 'r') as file:
   csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=";")
   ...
```

But since I'm trying to get the file from an upload button, i.e. an `input` HTML element of type `file`, as mentioned above, I'm getting a `FileStorage` object, which I'm not being able to read it.

Anyone has any idea how could I approach this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be that it's not encoded in `utf-8`. Try decoding it into `latin-1` instead:

```
file_data = file.read().decode("latin-1")
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem!