# How to open csv file uploaded from html form and determine row number by string python?

Tags: python, csv, flask

I have an html form where I am getting the user to select their bank and upload a CSV file of their transactions to handle financial data:

[image: form]

I can store the file in a variable named 'file' but can't find a way to open it with traditional methods:

e.g. this doesn't work

[image: getting file]

[image: method]

I know the file is valid in the python code because I can open it with pandas, it messes up the column headings as there is some preamble data in the file.

Here is the file:

[image: csv file]

I am trying to do this so I can search for a row number by string. I need to know what row number 'Date' is on so I can pass that value into skiprows() with pandas in order to get a correct dataframe. This is what I came up with so far:

[image: so far]

But obviously I cannot open the file in the first place. Ideally my output would be 7. I can't just use a static value of 7 for skiprows() with pandas as the amount of preamble data before the table changes from file to file.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?  The `files` dictionary is a set of `FIleStorage` objects.  You can use `file.save` to save it to disk, or you can use `file.read` to read the contents, which are stored in a temporary file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Cannot read from a FileStorage object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52666182/python-cannot-read-from-a-filestorage-object)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an optimal answer, but maybe it will work for you:

```
    file_content = file.stream.read().decode("UTF8")
    lines = file_content.split('\n')
```

Then you can look for the line starting with Date to figure your skiprows value.